# How to bind a list of checkboxes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of checkboxes as following :

```
<div flex="50" ng-repeat="formationType in formationTypeList">
            <md-checkbox class="md-warn md-align-top-left"
                         value="{{formationType.codeFormation}}"
                         name="formationSelection[]"
                         ng-checked="formationSelection.indexOf(formationType) > -1"
                         ng-click="toggleFormationTypeSelection(formationType)">
              {{ formationType.nom }}
            </md-checkbox>
          </div>
```

This is the format of `formationSelection` after I send my form :

```
formationSelection = [
{
  codeFormation: 1,
  nom: "ENSA"
},
{
  codeFormation: 2,
  nom: "CPGE"
}
]
```

In another scenario I want when I open my form to check the checkboxes which are defined in an array as following :

```
$scope.formationSelection = res.candidatureProjetProfessionnel.formations;
```

the object `res.candidatureProjetProfessionnel.formations` contains this :

```
formationSelection = [
{
  codeFormation: 1,
  nom: "ENSA"
},
{
  codeFormation: 2,
  nom: "CPGE"
}
]
```

And when I inspect `$scope.formationSelection` it contains the data I got from `res.candidatureProjetProfessionnel.formations` :

[image]

But I don't know why my checkboxes are not checked even though the `$scope.formationSelection` is not empty.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure what the `md-checkbox` directive is so i'm just going to use a normal checkbox input. Generally speaking, setting a default value for inputs in angular involves 2 things:

- Make sure your inputs have `ng-model` to store the value of the checkbox and for 2 way data binding (so that you can set it from the controller as well)
- In your controller set the variable declared in the ng-model to whatever default value you want.

So in you html:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="md-warn md-align-top-left" ng-
model="formationSelection[$index]" ng-true-value="{{formationType}}" 
name="formationSelection[]">
```

Make sure you use [ng-true-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) to declare the value of each checkbox when checked. The ng-model is set to `formationSelection[$index]` which basically means each checkbox is an item inside the formationSelection array, this way the array will be the collection of the values of all checked inputs.

Now `$scope.formationSelection = res.candidatureProjetProfessionnel.formations` should work

Here's a working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sGm39DRWH9EOReiiSrIl?p=preview

Comment: `md-checkbox` for material design UIs.Please see this :https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox

Comment: thanks this worked and now I dont need to use `ng-checked="formationSelection.indexOf(formationType) > -1"` and neither `ng-click="toggleFormationTypeSelection(formationType)">`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ng-model` as shown below.It should be an object like `$scope.data = {};`.This is just an example where hope you can get the point and work on your scenario. Actually you're having individual check boxes as shown below but values are being set through the loop.So you can apply this concept for your use case as well.Hope this will help to you.

***Html***

```
 <md-checkbox ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
            Checkbox 1: {{ data.cb1 }}
 </md-checkbox>
```

***JS***

```
 $scope.data = {};
 $scope.data.cb1 = true;
```

Play with it on [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Sampath-Lokuge/pen/Wwaprb)

Comment: thanks for your answer, in this case it wont work because I dont have my checkboxes declared statically, and `ng-checked="formationSelection.indexOf(formationType) > -1"` should work since it will set to true if it finds the current `formationType` in the `formationSelection` array

Comment: Why can't you set the `ng-model` here ? But one thing the `ng-model` must be an `object`.You have to organise it in that way.Just setting `true` or `false` will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your method `isFormation(formationType)` on the directive `ng-checked` it's not return the result.

In your controller create a function

```
$scope.isFormation(_type){
  return $scope.formationSelection.filter(function(f){return f.nom === _type;}).length > 0;
}
```